# AngularJS ui-router resolve of REST resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working on an application that photographers can use to upload photos. The frontend is AngularJS and there is a RESTfull api backend.

Because of some issues and the fact that ui-router seems better then ngRouter, I decided to change the $routeprovider to $stateProvider of ui-router.

However, my resolve doesn't work anymore (I guessed it would break but I cannot find the solution to my situation).

So here is the original $routeprovider code:

```
.when('/photographer', {
  templateUrl : '/static/partials/photographer/photographer_dash.html',
  controller : 'photographerController',
  resolve: {
    photogPrepService: function (PhotogService) {
      return PhotogService.ownPhotos();
    }
  }
})
```

The PhotogService is a $resource service that has the following $resource objects:

```
return $resource(apiHost, {}, {
            'ownPhotos': {
                url: apiHost + '/photographer_own_photos/',
                method: 'GET',
                interceptor: ResponseInterceptor
            }
});
```

In the controller I would then do the following (photogPrepService being injected because of the resolve):

```
var promise = photogPrepService;
promise.then(
function (data) {
    $scope.ownPhotos = data.data.photos;
});
```

This all worked well and I would get the photos in the scope.

However as said with ui-router it doesn't work and I cannot seem to get it working...

According to the docs (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) the following should work:

```
$stateProvider.state('photographer',
  {
    url: '/photographer',
    templateUrl: '/static/partials/photographer/photographer_dash.html',
    controller: 'photographerController',
    resolve: {
      photogPrepService: function (PhotogService) {
        return PhotogService.ownPhotos();
      }
    }
```

However, when the resolve is injected in the controller and I use console.log() to print the response, I get the following:

```
Resource(value)
```

I somehow cannot seem to get the values (JSON response {"photos": ...}) injected into the controller.. I tried various solutions that have been suggested here on stackoverflow and read guides and the API of ui-router, but I cannot wrap my head around what is going wrong... I hope someone can guide me in the right direction..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the code below:

```
//the PhotogService will keep the same as before

//inject the 'PhotogService' into the controller photographerController
PhotogService.ownPhotos().then(function(data) {
    $scope.ownPhotos = data.data.photos;
});

//instead of injecting the photogPrepService through 'resove', inject the PhotogService into the controller
//for the $stateProvider
$stateProvider.state('photographer',
{
    url: '/photographer',
    templateUrl: '/static/partials/photographer/photographer_dash.html',
    controller: 'photographerController',
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The reason I thought a resolve is the way to go is because there might be multiple states that use the same controller. Not all of these states need the ownPhotos call to be made. 

Doesn't this execute the ownPhotos call every time the controller is used?

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a promise to the resolve, your ressource should look more like :

```
$stateProvider.state('photographer',
{
  url: '/photographer',
  templateUrl: '/static/partials/photographer/photographer_dash.html',
  controller: 'photographerController',
  resolve: {
    photogPrepService: function (PhotogService) {
      return PhotogService.ownPhotos().$promise;
    }
  }
});
```

Or modify your ressources to make them promises.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried using .$promise in the state. However, it doesn't  work. It still returns the API calls as `Resource(value)` . However, in the resolve it does return the `$promise` , but not after it is injected..

I will look into modifying the resources. Thanks!